# Inequality related to random variable (Prove or disprove)?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, inequality, random-variables

Prove or disprove:  Two random random variables   $X_1, X_2$  such that $X_1 \geq X_2$  almost surely on the probability space $(\Omega, \mathbb{P})$. Then prove or disprove $X_1-Z \geq X_2 - Z$ almost surely on the same probability space.
Here $Z$ is also a random variable.

I feel it is true. But could not able to prove it. It will be really helpful if someone throw some light. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $E$ be set with probability $0$ such that $X_1(\omega) \geq X_2(\omega)$ for all $\omega \notin E$. Then $\omega \notin E$ implies $X_1(\omega)-Z(\omega) \geq X_2(\omega)-Z(\omega)$ and we are done!

Comment: Thank you Sir. I understand. I have one more query. From the above relation, Can I say that: $Max\{ X_1(\omega)-Z(\omega),0 \} \geq \ Max\{ X_2(\omega)- Z(\omega),0 \}$ ?

Comment: Yes, that is also correct.

Comment: Thank you so much